# How to write multiple joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to a join a table with a second table created from another join. I'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly. I am receving an error code that "Every derived table must have its own alias". Creating an alias is not something I have done before. Could you please let me know how to adjust my query? Thank you.

```
Select 
    questionnaire_status.* 
FROM                
    questionnaire_status        
LEFT JOIN    
    (SELECT 
        rep_list.Last_Name,    
        rep_list.First_Name,
        dept_codes.dept_name
     FROM
        rep_list
     Left Join
        dept_codes
     ON 
        rep_list.dept =dept_codes.dept_id
    )
ON     
    questionnaire_status.RR = rep_list.RR        
WHERE 
    questionnaire_Status.Attestation_submitted = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using subquerys, something you should not do unless absolutely necessary. (<- Performance is very bad)
Better are Multiple Joins are like this:

```
SELECT
    questionnaire_status.*,
    rep_list.Last_Name,    
    rep_list.First_Name,
    dept_codes.dept_name 
FROM                
    questionarrie_status
LEFT JOIN
    rep_list
ON   
    questionnaire_status.RR = rep_list.RR
LEFT JOIN
    dept_codes
ON
    rep_list = dept_codes.dept_id
LEFT JOIN
    questionarrie_status

WHERE 
    questionnaire_Status.Attestation_submitted = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `as` keyword to alias a subquery thus:

```
Select 
        questionnaire_status.* 
    FROM                
        questionnaire_status        
    LEFT JOIN    
        (SELECT 
            rep_list.Last_Name,    
            rep_list.First_Name,
            rep_list.RR,
            dept_codes.dept_name
         FROM
            rep_list
         Left Join
            dept_codes
         ON 
            rep_list.dept =dept_codes.dept_id
        ) as tbl_alias
    ON     
        questionnaire_status.RR = tbl_alias.RR        
    WHERE 
        questionnaire_Status.Attestation_submitted = '0
```

but you need to add the join column to the inner select as above

Answer (score 0):

To get the results I *think* you're trying to get, all you have to do is this:

```
Select
    questionnaire_status.*
FROM
    questionnaire_status
LEFT JOIN rep_list ON questionnaire_status.RR = rep_list.RR
LEFT JOIN dept_codes ON rep_list.dept = dept_codes.dept_id
```

As for the aliases, when you do this you're creating the alias "me":

```
SELECT * FROM myTable me;
```

MySQL was complaining about your subquery not having an alias:

```
(SELECT
    rep_list.Last_Name,
    rep_list.First_Name,
    dept_codes.dept_name
 FROM
    rep_list
 Left Join
    dept_codes
 ON
    rep_list.dept =dept_codes.dept_id
)
  ^^^ It wanted an alias here, to cover the subquery
```

So the next time you have a subquery, do something like this:

```
(SELECT
    rep_list.Last_Name,
    rep_list.First_Name,
    dept_codes.dept_name
 FROM
    rep_list
 Left Join
    dept_codes
 ON
    rep_list.dept =dept_codes.dept_id
) REP
  ^^^ MySQL has an alias (named REP) so it's happy now
```